Number of positive roots of a sum of reciprocals
Is it true that for any $n\geq 1$, any $a_1,\cdots,a_n \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and any $b_1,\cdots, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$, the function:
$$
f(x) = \frac{b_1}{x+a_1} + \frac{b_2}{x+a_2} + \cdots + \frac{b_n}{x+a_n}
$$
always have at most 1 positive real root, i.e. at most one $x^* \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $f(x^*) = 0$?
I ran some experiments on Mathematica, here's an example output for some randomized $a_k, b_k, k=1,\cdots,n$:

The graph always shows 1 positive root, or no positive root at all. I also checked the polynomial $g(x) := \prod_{i=1}^n(x+a_i)f(x)$, and it looks like the sign of the coefficients always change at most once. This is consistent with the descartes rule of signs.
Could anyone help me prove the claim, or provide me a counter-example?
In fact, what I really need for what I'm doing is the following special case: Is it true that for any $n \geq 1, n' \geq 1$, any $a_1,\cdots,a_n, a'_1,\cdots, a'_{n'} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and $C\geq 1$, the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x+a_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x+a_n} - C\left(\frac{1}{x+a'_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x+a'_{n'}}\right)
$$
always have at most 1 positive real root? But I thought it would also be interesting to investigate the more general statement.

Technically $n=n'$, $a_i=a'_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $C=1$ has infinitely many positive zeroes as $f(x)=0$.

We may assume that $0<a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_n.$  Let a polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $n-1$  have all positive roots. We have
$$f(x)={q(x)\over (x+a_1)(x+a_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+a_n)}\\ ={b_1\over x+a_1}+ {b_2\over x+a_2}+\ldots+  {b_n\over x+a_n}$$ for some real  coefficients $b_j$. Hence $f(x)$ has $n-1$ positive roots.
For example the function $$f(x)={(x-1)(x-2)\over (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}$$ has two positive roots.
Remark The conclusion holds if all $b_j$ have the same sign or one $b_j$ has opposite sign to all the remaining coefficients $b_i.$

Thank you! What about the more specific form: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+a_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x+a_n} - C\left(\frac{1}{x+a'1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x+a'{n'}}\right)$, do you know if the conclusion holds (i.e. at most one positive root)?
